# Mat nil when reading and writing images with openCV in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

Read Image (`tiff`) files in IOS (objectiv-C).
Save data as `NSString*` and cast as `cv::String`.

So far, the string I want is stored in a variable.

```
NSString* strTiff = call.arguments[@"Tiff"];
NSString* png = call.arguments[@"Path"];

cv::String test1 = [strTiff cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];;
cv::String test2 = [png cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];;
          
cv::Mat tiffImage = cv::imread(test1);
bool res = cv::imwrite(test2, tiffImage);
```

But when I run `cv::Imread();`, `cv::Mat tiffImage` image is saved as `nil`. Looking at the official documentation, there seems to be no problem with how to use it, but why is nil returned?

**tiffImage Data**

```
(cv::Mat) tiffImage = {
  flags = 1124007936
  dims = 0
  rows = 0
  cols = 0
  data = 0x0000000000000000
  datastart = 0x0000000000000000
  dataend = 0x0000000000000000
  datalimit = 0x0000000000000000
  allocator = nil
  u = nil
  size = {
    p = 0x000000016cf41098
  }
  step = {
    p = 0x000000016cf410e0
    buf = ([0] = 0, [1] = 0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"But when I run cv::Imread();, cv::Mat tiffImage image is saved as nil."
allocator = nil
opencv read image fail with tiffImage is nil.
opencv save image will definitely fail.
You need to determine whether the image path and opencv are readable.

```
 NSString* readFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"read.png"];
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:readFilePath];
NSLog(@"image:%@", image);

cv::String readpath_str = [readFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
cv::Mat image_mat = cv::imread(readpath_str);

NSString* saveFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"write.png"];
cv::String writepath_str = [saveFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
bool res = cv::imwrite(writepath_str, image_mat);
NSLog(@"cm write:%d", res);
```

Comment: `readFilePath` and `image` are not `nil`. But still the error exists. The error is `error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
cv::Mat tiffImage = cv::imread(test1);
```

change

```
cv::Mat tiffImage;
UIImageToMat(image, tiffImage, true);
```